# Java - Enterprise и Web в чем отличие?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Прочитал прилично статей, но так и не понял главную суть:

1. Enterprise: тяжелые серверные приложения для банков, корпораций, инвестфондов и тд.
2. Web - лидирует PHP, но и Java держит солидный кусок рынка.

Не понимаю почему отделяют эти 2 категории, вот допустим взять приложение для банка. Там будет front-end и back-end. Бекенд мы будем писать на Spring Framework допустим, а это веб-разработка точнее одна из его видов. Тогда почему делят Enterprise и Web?

Comment: Ну, в Java они и не отделяются, стандартные пакеты для web-разработки находятся в составе стандарта Java EE. Но важно понимать, что enterprise - это не только web.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Можете привести примеры, что это не только веб? А то я только веб видел

Comment: В Java EE входит около 40 стандартов. Из них к web относится штук 6-9. Тот же EJB для разработки сайтов не нужен. Та же история со Spring - из более, чем 20 проектов, входящих в него, к web-разработке относятся только MVC и WebFlux. В банках есть куча написанных на Java enterprise-систем с web вообще никак не связанных.